# Objective-Zip ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, zip

New to objective c and would love to use the objective-zip framework for unzipping and zipping files.

https://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

Obviously when I compiled it, with arc, it gave me a lot of warnings. So I set the no arc flag for all the files inside of objective-zip folder (compiles fine now, no warnings).

My question is, since the example in the tarball uses manual memory management, should I change any of the files to use it with ARC (the objective-zip class files)?

or is this all I do?

[Creating a ZIP file from a folder in documents directory - Objective C (ARC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649468/creating-a-zip-file-from-a-folder-in-documents-directory-objective-c-arc)

I'd also love someone to give a general guideline on how to approach these sorts of things.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171922/switching-the-non-arc-project-into-arc

Comment: I respectfully disagree, but for sure there is some other similar question. In any case, the answer to the question is, if the code follows standard naming practices - ie init does not return an autoreleased object, then you can include the files (marked as non ARC) or even a library (.a) or a project that makes a .a. As a general rule you will find that most projects on the web that get any usage at all will follow standard practices and will work just fine. I used JSONKit, a non-ARC project, in my first ARC app with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the arc converter inside of xcode and it worked great!

Thanks ZangChn!

```
    IMHO, dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171922/switching-the-non-arc-project-into-arc

    ~ZhangChn 
    Sep 24 at 7:28
    (on stack overflow)
```