# Last Xcode to support non-ARC to ARC conversion

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, xcode10, xcode10.1

Which latest Xcode version supports converting non-ARC project to ARC?

Currently, I'm using Xcode 10 and the following answer doesn't apply to it. [Switching the non ARC project into ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171922/switching-the-non-arc-project-into-arc)

To which version should I roll back in order to automatically convert the project?

Comment: Xcode 10.1 still has that option, so what do you mean by "doesn't apply"?

Comment: How to open it?

Comment: Edit -> Convert -> To Objective-C ARC…

Comment: Thanks, I actually found it now. There were no "refactor" option, neither I was able to find it in "refactoring" dropdown.

Comment: Yeah, they reworded it a bit :)